# Testing spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I am testing my controller using mockito junit framework.

I got stuck in the controller layer where I get null pointer exception in UserDetails interface.

I tried to override the interface but still I face the problem.

This is my default **controller** only for userDetails interface to get the user information.

```
public class DefaultController {


    public UserDetails getUserDetails(){
        UserDetails userDetails=null;
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
               userDetails = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        }
        return userDetails;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getUserCSRoles(){
        Set<Integer> csroles=new HashSet<Integer>();
        UserDetails userDetails=getUserDetails();
        if(userDetails!=null)
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : userDetails.getAuthorities()) {
            if(grantedAuthority.getAuthority().split("_").length>1){
            if(grantedAuthority.getAuthority().split("_")[1].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("MANAGER")){
                csroles.add(1);
            }else if(grantedAuthority.getAuthority().split("_")[1].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("SHAREDSERVICE")){
                csroles.add(2);
            }else if(grantedAuthority.getAuthority().split("_")[1].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")){
                csroles.add(3);
            }else if(grantedAuthority.getAuthority().split("_")[1].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("SUPERADMIN")){
                csroles.add(3);
            }
            }
        }
        return csroles;
    }
```

This is my **managaer controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value="new",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testMethod(@ModelAttribute("employeeDetails") EmployeeDetails details,HttpSession httpSession, Model model){
        UserDetails userDetails = getUserDetails();
        model.addAttribute("details", details);
        return "redirect:newemployee";
    }
```

And the for **testing the manager**  this is what I have done:

```
@Test
    public void testnewEmployeePost() throws Exception{
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails() {

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public String getUsername() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "nitesh";
            }

            @Override
            public String getPassword() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "nitesh";
            }

            @Override
            public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                GrantedAuthority authority = new GrantedAuthority() {

                    @Override
                    public String getAuthority() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return "ROLE_USER";
                    }
                };
                List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                grantedAuthorities.add(authority);
                return grantedAuthorities;
            }
        };

        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails();
        employeeDetails.setPanCardNo("lower");
        employeeDetails.setFirstName("Nitesh");

        Mockito.when(managerController.getUserDetails()).thenReturn(userDetails);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/manager/new")
                .contentType(MediaType.ALL)
                .sessionAttr("employeeDetails", employeeDetails)
                )   
                .andExpect(model().attribute("employeeDetails", instanceOf(EmployeeDetails.class)));
    }
```

And the **exception thrown** is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rectrix.ool.controller.DefaultController.getUserDetails(DefaultController.java:24)
    at com.rectrix.ool.test.controller.TestManagerController.testnewEmployeePost(TestManagerController.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Kindly guide me to overcome this issue

Comment: What is line:24 ? in DefaultController ?

Comment: if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {


line 24:        userDetails = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
  }

  return userDetails;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create an annonymous `UserDetails` instance. You can use `User` which is an implementation of the `UserDetails` already available in Spring Security. Anyway it is not even required. And you are trying to mock the Parent Class `DefaultController` of the `ManagerController`. I have never seen or heard the ability to mock a is a relationship. What you should do is import dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And rewrite your test as following to mock an authenticated user.

```
 import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user;

    @Test
    public void testnewEmployeePost() throws Exception{


        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails();
        employeeDetails.setPanCardNo("lower");
        employeeDetails.setFirstName("Nitesh");

        mockMvc.perform(post("/manager/new")
            .with(user("nitesh")
            .password("nitesh")
            .authorities(AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"))
        .contentType(MediaType.ALL)
        .sessionAttr("employeeDetails", employeeDetails))   
        .andExpect(model().attribute("employeeDetails", instanceOf(EmployeeDetails.class)));
    }
```

Comment: Ya i did the same way like you said now, still i found the same null pointer error as shown below.
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.rectrix.ool.controller.DefaultController.getUserDetails(DefaultController.java:24)
 at com.rectrix.ool.controller.ManagerController.testMethod(ManagerController.java:547)

Comment: I also one small doubt, How to overcome the circular view path exception. My get method url and the return to view string is the same. For instance if my url  of the get method is /manager/new and the return string iis also the the same like /manager/new, this would take me to the jsp and navigate to the post method from there. Since the project is developed I cannot be change the url or nither the return string, but now how can I overcome this is issue for testing.

Comment: I have also posted this query in stackoverflow, but I seem no response. kindly help and here is my link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333395/spring-mvc-controller-testing-using-junit-and-mockito-circular-view-path-excep